# Eevee output low res

Tags: rendering, video, encoding

When I render animation and output to mpeg4 it's a very very low res file and quality. How do I fix this? I'm using Blender 2.8 and I'm new. 1920 1080 is what I have entered, I have also selected ff and h.264. I've also noticed it outputs it to an mkv file and not mp4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For .mp4 output you need to select the MPEG-4 container. The output quality can be changed by setting the "Ouput Quality".

[image]

Comment: Can you define output quality please?

Comment: @KamranAli Check the field marked red that currently says "Medium quality". You can select whatever suits your needs, it's always a trade off between quality and file size. Lossless is obviously best for quality, but the file size will be huge.